# Using An Update Query

Tags: php, mysql

What could be wrong with this update query?

```
"UPDATE relationships SET status='4' WHERE user_1= $user_1, user_2= $user_2";
```

Answer (score 4):

```
UPDATE relationships SET status='4' WHERE user_1 = :user_1 AND user_2= :user_2
```

And since you've tagged this as a MySQL question, I would suggest that you should switch to PDO and use prepared statements, because the PHP community has begun process of deprecation for the old ext/mysql extension (which provides `mysql_*` functions).

[Here](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) is a nice link on how to work with PDO.

Comment: Sir, LOL I say. `mysql_*` extension is being deprecated!

Comment: -1 That `net.tutsplus.com` link is filled with mistakes and bad practices.

Answer (score 0):

```
"UPDATE relationships " .
"SET status = '4' " .
"WHERE user_1 = '" . $user_1 . "' AND user_2 = '" . $user_2 . "'";
```